# Firebase key reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a simple transaction to a firebase database, however, I'm not having luck getting around the firebase generated keys for each account.  here is my JSON:

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-KRPSyO4B48IpBnHBTYg" : {
      "newRecord" : "100",
      "email" : "",
      "provider" : "",
      "userId" : ""
    }
  },
  "products" : {
    "-KUKRafaNurpFhGF4jQa" : {
      "name" : ""
    }
  },
}
```

I want to add a count to "newRecord" to the same level as userId, provider and email. However I am not successful with the following, or any variation so far:

```
 firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + accounts.id).transaction(function(value) {
  if (value) {
    value.newRecord++;

  }
  return value;

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `accounts` object look like? if it is the javascript equivalent of your displayed JSON, then `accounts.id` is undefined - there is no `id` attribute in the `accounts` object. So, it appears you're effectively creating a transaction on an invalid firebase ref.

Comment: Yes that is what happens with that line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer the value directly while using the transaction.

```
firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + accounts.id+'/newRecord').transaction(function(value) {
if (value) {
value++;
}
return value;
});
```